# Objects do not appear in rendered image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects

My son is working on the BlenderGuru’s donut lesson.
Everytime he tries to render the image, the donut and the coffee mug don’t show up in the render.  The icing and everything else does.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: are the camera icons in the outliner enabled?

Comment: Please **read carefully** through the many solutions the following link:[Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)  If none of those solutions work for you, use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project.  Also, [add some images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Answer (score -1):

Shift select the other layers, you need them selected to render.